# The opposite of "wanted"

Tags: word-request

When a person is **wanted** everybody wants to work with him, he's popular and is always asked for. But is there an opposite for **wanted**, meaning a person who isn't popular at work, someone whom nobody wants to work with.

I was thinking of the word **outcast** but I doubt it can refer to such a meaning considering its definition.

I would like to fit it into this context:

- My friend is always wanted while I am always [this word].

Comment: Are you passively "ingored", or  actively <something (e.g. unwanted)>?

Comment: @Mawg Let's say both are possible. The reason is unknown.

Comment: Maybe: My friend is always wanted while I am always *overlooked*

Comment: There are probably 50 ways to say this.  You can be unchosen, unwanted, avoided, bypassed, overlooked, disregarded, shunned, snubbed... You have made the context so vague that many words which mean rather different things could fit.

Comment: How about unwanted? :P

Comment: Maybe infamous? It is like famous but means more like well known for bad or unwanted characteristics rather than good ones.

Comment: Oh gush, so many variants, I have no idea which one to use.

Comment: You should be careful saying someone is "wanted" without context. It can also mean they are a criminal at large that the police are searching for. Look at "[wanted poster](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wanted_poster)".

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I immediately associate "wanted" with "dead or alive".

Comment: I would not say anybody is "wanted", unless the police is looking for them. Maybe you could use "popular" or "in demand" or something similar.

Comment: "Unappreciated" is what comes to my mind.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The obvious answers are the words you've mentioned, but with *un* prepended: **unpopular** or **unwanted**.

(Edit) You can also say **reject**, in the sense of "social rejection." For example: "My friend is always wanted while I am always getting *rejected*". It also works as a noun, like "I am a social *reject*."

Comment: Unwanted and unpopular aren't the words I'm looking for. They don't mean what I exactly need.

Comment: "unwanted" is my favorite.

Comment: @SovereignSun then wanted and popular aren't the correct words you're meant to be describing either

Comment: `"Unwanted and unpopular aren't the words I'm looking for"`, still accepts the answer

Comment: @Denny ppl do strange stuff :|

Comment: @Denny I've changed my mind. Only a fool doesn't change his mind, I am not.

Answer (score 14):

You could easily say that "people (at work) avoid him", but if you want to use an adjective (grammatically speaking a past participle used as an adjective) you could use *shunned*.

Definition of shun:

- [in the wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shun): "to avoid, especially persistently."
- [in Cambridge online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/shun) : "to ignore someone and not speak to that person because you cannot accept their behaviour, beliefs, etc."

Here are examples of the use of the word in this context:

In a book about Michael Jackson:

- > A man who won eight Grammys just four years earlier was shunned on that night; (*[Michael Jackson & the Music That Was](https://books.google.fr/books?id=KStaDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT60&dq=was%20shunned&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=was%20shunned&f=false)*, The Voice of One, 2016)

In a conversation in a contemporary "romance":

- > My mother, you see, was shunned when she became pregnant with Roland and me. (*[Mated in Mist: A Paranormal Shifter Talon Pack Romance](https://books.google.fr/books?id=6Tw1CgAAQBAJ&pg=PT50&dq=was%20shunned&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=was%20shunned&f=false)*, Carrie Ann Ryan, 2016)

In an autobiography:

- > At play time I was shunned. The boys and girls didn't want to talk to me.
  >   (*[He Touched Me: An Autobiography](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ghePZwMqY3sC&pg=PT16&dq=was%20shunned&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=was%20shunned&f=false)*, Benny Hinn, 2001)

In a detective novel:

- > You knew what would happen to his family if he was shunned. (*[Roots of Murder](https://books.google.fr/books?id=RSkQ6j4nS_AC&pg=PT179&dq=was%20shunned&hl=fr&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=was%20shunned&f=false)*, Janis Harrison, 1999)

In the written press:

- > Those born on Skye are shunned if they say anything against the wind farm. They no longer exist. ([*The Telegraph*](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1491421/Those-born-on-Skye-are-shunned-if-they-say-anything-against-the-wind-farm.-They-no-longer-exist.html) - 05/06/2005)
- > They survived Ebola. Now they are shunned  (*[The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/to-your-health/wp/2014/08/13/they-survived-ebola-now-they-are-shunned/?utm_term=.cae04a4f974d)*, 13/08/2014)

Comment: In my experience, *shun* is a moderately uncommon word, more likely to appear in newspaper headlines (like the ones you provided) than in everyday speech or writing (mostly because it's slightly too formal).

Comment: @Kevin OP did not say if a was looking for a word for everyday oral use or to use in a text and did not specify any register.   Shunned  is not only a word you can read in newspaper headlines, you can read it in lots of writings. I'll add examples from various recent writings, and you can find thousands more if you search.

Comment: I was just remarking on the relative formality of the word.  I never said it was exclusive to headlines.

Comment: @Kevin And I was just remarking it was quite frequent in non formal writings - even in conversation.

Answer (score 10):

What about *unwelcome*?

> [unwelcome](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unwelcome)
>   :  not wanted or welcome • unwelcome news • an unwelcome guest
>   (M-W)

This is especially apt if you are trying to join some groups or activities.

I think the simple *avoided* could work:

> [avoid](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/avoid)
>   transitive verb
>   1 a :  to keep away from :  shun • They have been avoiding me.
>   (M-W)

*Ignored* could work, especially if you are actively trying to get everyone's attention or approval. In my opinion, the first part of the sentence implies that it is because you are not wanted.

> [ignore](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ignore)
>   transitive verb
>   1 :  to refuse to take notice of
>   (M-W)

Answer (score 8):

There are some good answers, but I wanted to add [Pariah](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pariah) to the mix.

> - one that is despised or rejected

In your sample sentence, it would read like:

> My friend is always wanted while I am always (treated like) a pariah.

It *is* pretty strong though. You wouldn't necessarily use it to describe a one-off situation, rather if the rejection was a fairly regular occurrence.

Answer (score 6):

If you want something with a negative ring to it you can use

> scorned
>
> 1. a. Contempt or disdain felt toward a person or object considered despicable or unworthy: viewed his rivals with scorn.
>      b. The expression of such an attitude in behavior or speech; derision: heaped scorn upon his rivals.
>      c. The state of being despised or dishonored: held in scorn by his rivals.
> 2. Archaic One spoken of or treated with contempt.
>      tr.v. scorned, scorn·ing, scorns
> 3. To consider or treat as contemptible or unworthy: an artist who was scorned by conservative critics.
> 4. To reject or refuse with derision: scorned their offer of help. See Synonyms at despise.
> 5. To consider or reject (doing something) as beneath one's dignity

Comment: _Scorn_ is a viable suggestion, but I think it may be a little too harsh in some cases. Learners should know this is a rather strong word.

Answer (score 3):

*Disliked.*

From Cambridge:

> [**Dislike**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dislike) (*noun*) a feeling of not liking something or someone.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, **outcast** is a pretty good word to use here. The usage would be like so:

> My friend is always wanted, while I'm always the outcast.

or as others have noted, if you're not actively cast out of groups but rather just not noticed:

> My friend is always wanted, while I'm always overlooked.
>
> My friend is always wanted, while I go unnoticed.

Answer (score 3):

> [Undesireable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undesirable)

Either in the adjective form:

> having qualities that are not pleasing or wanted an undesirable effect

or the noun form

> one that is undesirable

Seem to fit here.

Comment: Or 'undesired'. It has the same meaning as 'un-wanted' without the negative connotation of actively not wanting something.

Answer (score 1):

**Repulsive** would fit in case where you describe a person you don't want to work with, but with a more emotional (they behave badly, smell/look unpleasantly), rather than objective (if they are a low productivity worker) sense.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like **out of place** would fit here.

> [Out of place](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/out+of+place): [...]
>
> 3. Fig. [of someone ] awkward and unwelcome. (*Typically: be ~; feel ~; seem ~.) I feel out of place at formal dances. Bob and Ann felt out of place at the picnic, so they went home.

- My friend is always wanted while (I am always/I always feel) out of place.

Answer (score 1):

I like Anathema, myself.  As in, "Gideon was anathema at the office."  It has the connotation of someone who is avoided, shunned, and held in low regard.

> Anathema, in common usage, is something or someone that is detested or shunned.  In its other main usage, it is a formal excommunication. The latter meaning, its ecclesiastical sense, is based on New Testament usage. [Wikipedia](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjY47aC9-jTAhWB5YMKHb-RDt0QmhMIjwEwDQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FAnathema&usg=AFQjCNEFi5yzHan5-hs4guOwCqOMQZ_yNQ&sig2=z7GCquHg5nyRjKnt-vXrGw)

Answer (score -1):

Current recommendations are good. `Unwanted` is probably best since it's by nature the opposite of `wanted`.

If you want to go with a different word with similar meaning, I might go with something along the lines of `feared`.

> I wanted cake for dinner.
>
> I feared pork for dinner.